# AWS and HTTP2 - Having HTTPS configured on application load balancer

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, https, http2, elastic-load-balancer

I discovered that configure HTTPS on the AWS applications LB is the easiest way to secure my website and even use HTTP/2 with HTTPS listeners.

But, surprisingly, when AWS Application LB distribuite the requests across the servers, [all the requests are converted in HTTP/1.1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-configuration).

I understand that I'll notice fewer connections between clients and the load balancer but all the requests behind the Application LB were sent in HTTP/1.1.

So the question is, what are in your opinion the drawbacks of this solution?

Could I effectively say that my website is served in HTTP/2 (even if I can't use the server-push feature)?

Comment: First, only the newer Application Load Balancers support HTTP/2. Where are you seeing it documented that Application Load Balancers can only communicate with the back-end servers via HTTP/1.1?

Comment: @MarkB In the question I have referenced the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-configuration)  with a link. In my question (as in the title) I refer clearly to Application load balancer.

Comment: Thanks, I missed your link.

Comment: The balancer nodes reuse connections, holding open a handful of spare kept-alive connections to the instances, and use them to distribute the parallel requests across the instances.  This is better load sharing than what you'd have native HTTP/2 on the instances.  I don't see the concern.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for your comment. To be clear, is not a concern, it is just to understand what's happening under the hood. For example, I  realise the reuse of connection, but in this way the web application is still remain HTTP/1.1. What do I loose, only the server-push feature?

Comment: I see.  From the browser's perspective, the site speaks HTTP/2.  I can't authoritatively say that server push is the *only* thing you'd lose... but I don't look at it as a "lose" proposition -- I see it as gaining capabilities over end-to-end HTTP/1.x.  If you want to deploy HTTP/2 on your instances directly, you can always use an ELB Classic to spread the connections across back-ends, and what you lose there is the scattering of requests across backends, because each browser makes only one connection through one balancer node to one instance.